# retrieving multiple model objects from rails partial form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the below form working as a partial, i'm trying to do a partial call for a Contractors models and i want to also pass the current page's model id which is a quote id.

Its failing on this line <%= hidden_field_tag :quote_id, @quote.id %>  'called id for nil'

I've tried creating a manual route and putting the search on a seperate method, but then i get a template error so i'm just leaving it in the index method for now.

Form in show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag quotes_path, :method => 'get', :id => "contractors_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  <br><br><br>
  <div id="contractors"><%= render 'contractors' %></div>
<% end %>
```

_contractors.html.erb

```
<table>
<% @contractors.each do | contractor | %>
<tr>
    <td><%= contractor.firstname %></td>
    <td>
    <%= form_tag (quote_add_contractor_path) do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :quote_id, @quote.id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :contractor_id, contractor.id %>
        <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
    <% end %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Index.js.erb

```
$("#contractors").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "contractors") %>");
```

Controller:

```
def index

    @quotes = Quote.all  
    @contractors = Contractor.search(params[:search]) 


end


def add_contractor
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:quote_id])
    @contractor = Contractor.find(params[:contractor_id])
    @quote.contractors << @contractor

    if @quote.save
        redirect_to @quote, notice: "contractor was added"
    else
        render :show, notice: "Sorry, something went aweful"
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.js.erb you render the partial contractors but you do not set the @quote instance variable in your index action of the controller. That is why you are getting this failure. Try to add `@quote = # Some logic here` to your index action.